# C++ Deep Copy Object

Tags: c++

I am trying to deep copy objects back and forth. When I run the gdb, I get the following error after one iteration of the loop.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804ab96 in DGCPM::DGCPM (this=0x844b760, cur=0x1) at DGCPM.C:27
27    memcpy(vRCells, cur->vRCells,sizeof(float)*nThetaCells);
```

I suspect the problem has to do with creating the "new class," but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

(Note: The "_initialize" code calls a FORTRAN subroutine that sets the values in the program.)

Here is the run.C main file:

```
#include "../include/DGCPM.h"

#define particle_num 5

class DGCPM **mallocModels(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  class DGCPM **m;
  class DGCPM **cur;

  m=mallocModels(particle_num);//update

 for(int t = 0; t < 48; t++){

      //Update m, and then...
      cur = m;
      m = (DGCPM**)malloc(sizeof(class DGCPM *)*particle_num);      
      for(int i=0;i<particle_num;i++){
randomidx = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1));
    currentidx = find(cumPw,randomidx,particle_num);
        m[i] = new class DGCPM(cur[currentidx]);
    }
      for(int i=0;i<particle_num;i++){
    delete cur[i];
    }
    free(cur);

  }

   return 0;
}


/*============================================================================
   mallocModels - allocate the ensemble of models
  ============================================================================*/
class DGCPM **mallocModels(int n){
  class DGCPM **m;

  m=(class DGCPM **)amjSafeMalloc(sizeof(class DGCPM *)*n,
              (char *)"mallocModels:m");

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    m[i]=new class DGCPM();

  return m;
}


/*============================================================================
  Find - Return a particle index that has a high probability of having a high weight.
  ============================================================================*/

int find(float *cumPw, double randomidx, int nM){
    /*Wrong implementation*/
        int index = 0;
        flag = 0;
    while(flag == 0){
        if(cumPw[i] >= randomidx){
        flag = 1;
        i++;
    }
        else{
        index ++;
        }
        }
    return index; //Sometimes, index was going to number of models, or number of models + 1, which are out of bounds.
/*Correct implementation*/
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nM-1; i++){
    if(cumPw[i] >= randomidx){
        index = i;
    break;
    }
    }   
    if(index >= nM){
    index = nM-1;
    printf("Error: random index exceeds bounds");
    }
    return index;
}
```

Here is the DGCPM.h header file:

```
class DGCPM{

public:
  DGCPM(); /* Initialized with defaults setup */
  DGCPM(class DGCPM *cur); //Copy constructor
  DGCPM(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, float thetaMax); 

  ~DGCPM(); /* Free memory */

private:
  int internal; /* 1=memory allocated internally and should be deallocated when ~DGCPM is called, 2=memory is internal except for mGridN which is external */
  int nThetaCells,nRCells,nPhiCells;
  float thetaMin,thetaMax;
  float rMin,rMax;
  float delR,delPhi;
  float deltMax;
  float *vRCells; /* [nThetaCells] */
  float *vThetaCells; /* [nThetaCells] */
  float *vPhiCells; /* [nPhiCells] */

  float **mGridB; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridBi; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridPot; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridEr; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridEp; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridVr; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridVp; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridN; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridHalf; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] Particles / weber (workspace for upwind and superbee) */
  float **mGridDen; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridVol; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridX; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridY; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **mGridOc; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float **std; /* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */
  float parI[2]; 
  float delTMax;
  float Re;

  void initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
          float thetaMax);

};
```

And finally the DGCPM.C object wrapper:

```
/******************************************************************************
 * DGCPM.C - This implements the DGCPM plasmasphere model class               *
 ******************************************************************************/
#define TWO_PI 6.2831853071795864769252866
#include "../include/DGCPM.h"
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cmath>

/*============================================================================
  DGCPM::DGCPM()

  Initialize with default setup
  ============================================================================*/
DGCPM::DGCPM(){

  internal=1;

  initialize(200,200,14.963217,60.0);/*(180,200,14.963217,60.0);*/
}

//Copy Constructor
DGCPM::DGCPM(class DGCPM *cur){

  internal=1;

  initialize(200,200,14.963217,60.0);/*(180,200,14.963217,60.0);*/

  memcpy(vRCells, cur->vRCells,sizeof(float)*nThetaCells);
  memcpy(vPhiCells, cur->vPhiCells,sizeof(float)*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(vThetaCells, cur->vThetaCells,sizeof(float)*nThetaCells);
  memcpy(mGridB[0], cur->mGridB[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridBi[0], cur->mGridBi[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridPot[0], cur->mGridPot[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridEr[0], cur->mGridEr[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridEp[0], cur->mGridEp[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridVr[0], cur->mGridVr[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridVp[0], cur->mGridVp[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridN[0], cur->mGridN[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridHalf[0], cur->mGridHalf[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridDen[0], cur->mGridDen[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridVol[0], cur->mGridVol[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridOc[0], cur->mGridOc[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(mGridX[0], cur->mGridX[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells); 
  memcpy(mGridY[0], cur->mGridY[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
  memcpy(std[0], cur->std[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);

} 


/*============================================================================
  DGCPM::~DGCPM()

  Free allocated memory
  ============================================================================*/
DGCPM::~DGCPM(){
  if(internal>=1){
    amjFree1dFloat(vRCells);
    amjFree1dFloat(vThetaCells);
    amjFree1dFloat(vPhiCells);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridB);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridBi);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridEr);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridEp);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridVr);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridVp);
    if(internal==1) amjFree2dFloat(mGridN);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridHalf);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridDen);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridVol);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridX);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridY);
    amjFree2dFloat(mGridOc);
    amjFree2dFloat(std);
  }
}


/******************************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************
 **                         Private functions                                **
 ******************************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/

/*============================================================================
  DGCPM::initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
          float thetaMax);

  This is the initialization function used when all memory should be
  allocated internally.
  ============================================================================*/
void DGCPM::initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
               float thetaMax){

  initialize(nThetaCells,nPhiCells,thetaMin,thetaMax,
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nThetaCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vRCells"),
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nThetaCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vThetaCells"),
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nPhiCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vPhiCells"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridB"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridBi"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridPot"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridEr"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridEp"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVr"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVp"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridN"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridHalf"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridDen"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVol"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridX"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridY"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridOc"),
         //Added by J.Wise

         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:std"));
}
/*============================================================================
  DGCPM::initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
          float thetaMax);

  This is the initialization function used when mGridN is passed from
  the outside but all other memory is allocated internally.
  ============================================================================*/
void DGCPM::initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
               float thetaMax, float **mGridN){

  initialize(nThetaCells,nPhiCells,thetaMin,thetaMax,
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nThetaCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vRCells"),
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nThetaCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vThetaCells"),
         amjMalloc1dFloat(nPhiCells,(char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:vPhiCells"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridB"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridBi"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridPot"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridEr"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridEp"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVr"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVp"),
         mGridN,
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridHalf"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridDen"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridVol"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridX"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridY"),
         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:mGridOc"),

         amjMalloc2dFloat(nPhiCells,nThetaCells,
                  (char *)"DGCPM::DGCPM:std"));

}

    /*
      initialize() - this initialization function uses pre-allocated
      memory areas passed in from the outside. This function is used both
      when DGCPM allocates memory itself and when it receives
      pre-allocated memory from the outside in order to eliminate
      duplication of code with the associated risk of errors. 
      ============================================================================*/
    void DGCPM::initialize(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells, float thetaMin, 
                   float thetaMax, float *vRCells, float *vThetaCells,
                   float *vPhiCells, float **mGridB, float **mGridBi, 
                   float **mGridPot, float **mGridEr, float **mGridEp,
                   float **mGridVr, float **mGridVp, float **mGridN, 
                   float **mGridHalf, float **mGridDen, float **mGridVol,
                   float **mGridX, float **mGridY, float **mGridOc, float **std){

      DGCPM::nThetaCells=nThetaCells;
      DGCPM::nPhiCells=nPhiCells;
      DGCPM::thetaMin=thetaMin;
      DGCPM::thetaMax=thetaMax;
      DGCPM::vRCells=vRCells;
      DGCPM::vThetaCells=vThetaCells;
      DGCPM::vPhiCells=vPhiCells;
      DGCPM::mGridB=mGridB;
      DGCPM::mGridBi=mGridBi;
      DGCPM::mGridPot=mGridPot;
      DGCPM::mGridEr=mGridEr;
      DGCPM::mGridEp=mGridEp;
      DGCPM::mGridVr=mGridVr;
      DGCPM::mGridVp=mGridVp;
      DGCPM::mGridN=mGridN;
      DGCPM::mGridHalf=mGridHalf;
      DGCPM::mGridDen=mGridDen;
      DGCPM::mGridVol=mGridVol;
      DGCPM::mGridX=mGridX;
      DGCPM::mGridY=mGridY;
      DGCPM::mGridOc=mGridOc;
      DGCPM::std=std;
      Re=6.378e6;



      initialize_(&nThetaCells,&nRCells,&nPhiCells,&thetaMin,&thetaMax,&rMin,&rMax,
              &delR,&delPhi,vRCells,vThetaCells,vPhiCells,mGridB[0],mGridBi[0],
              mGridN[0],mGridDen[0],mGridVol[0],mGridX[0],mGridY[0],mGridOc[0],std[0]);
    }
```

Here's a sample custom memory function, which takes care of initialization and allocation:

```
void *amjSafeMalloc(int n, char *message){

  void *d;

  d=malloc(n);

  if(d==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"amjSafeMalloc error: Could not allocate %d bytes "
        "for %s. Exiting.\n",n,message);
    exit(1);
  }

  return d;
} 

float *amjMalloc1dFloat(int a, char *message){

  float *d;

  sprintf(msg,"%s:amjMalloc1DFloat:d",message);
  d=(float *)amjSafeMalloc(sizeof(float)*a,msg);

  return d;
}

float **amjMalloc2dFloat(int a, int b, char *message){

  float **d;
  int i;

  sprintf(msg,"%s:amjMalloc2DFloat:d",message);
  d=(float **)amjSafeMalloc(sizeof(float *)*a,msg);
  sprintf(msg,"%s:amjMalloc2DFloat:d[0]",message);
  d[0]=(float *)amjSafeMalloc(sizeof(float)*a*b,msg);

  for(i=1;i<a;i++) d[i]=d[i-1]+b;

  return d;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ code? And does any of this compile? And you mix delete with free!

Comment: All of those naked pointers, dynamic allocation, and you didn't expect to see a seg fault somewhere?

Comment: Why do you cast string literals (which are usually read only) to `char*`? Are you 100% sure `amjMalloc2dFloat` will not try to modify the string?

Comment: Also, what's with the superfluous usage of the `class` keyword in your code? For example: `DGCPM(class DGCPM *cur)`. Also, that comment that goes with that line is wrong. That is *not* a copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks Ed and Paul. Paul, maybe you can kind of see what I'm trying to accomplish. How would you implement a copy constructor?

Comment: @JohnW. - Become friends with the STL - Use Vectors and most of the work is already done for you.

Comment: If you used vectors, it would deep copy for free.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings or up warning level (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc/clang, `/W3` for Visual C++) and fix any. Then try running under *valgrind* (Linux or Mac) if still unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This going to sound so stupid (elementary programming error): my index "i" was going beyond (number of models - 1), so I was getting a segmentation fault from accessing memory that didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
class DGCPM
{
public:
    DGCPM(int nThetaCells, int nPhiCells)
    : nThetaCells(nThetaCells)
    , nPhiCells(nPhiCells)
    , mGridB(nThetaCells, vector<float>(nPhiCells)) // first Y then X
    {
    }

private:
    int nThetaCells, nPhiCells;
    vector<vector<float>> mGridB;
};
```

Deep copies for free. Deletes memory for free.

By free I mean you don't have to write the code..

Comment: This is a really good solution, but I'm also interfacing with FORTRAN and CUDA and therefore need to keep pointers. =(

Comment: @John W. Well for vector<float>, you have the pointer. Just use the address of the first element of the vector. `vector<float> f;...foo(&f[0])` and foo() is a function that takes a float* as the argument. For 2-d arrays, you could create an object that handles the 2d arrays, instead of throwing around loose, disjoint code that is a nightmare to handle. I never used CUDA, but whatever the layout the 2-d array is supposed to take, create a class that does nothing but maintain the array.

Comment: @John W.  It isn't clear from your post how you're initializing those float** members.  I just see you declaring them, and then using them in a memcpy.  It is highly important you show us how you set up those float** members.  There are generally two ways:  1) allocate the row pointers, and then in a loop, allocate the column data for each pointer `OR` 2) allocate the row pointers, and then allocate *all* the column data in one single allocation.  I think it is the latter you need to be doing.  With the latter approach, the memory is one contiguous chunk, and then your memcpy() may work.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulMcKenzie. I added the 2D allocation function at the bottom.

Comment: For 2D arrays simply use a vector and change how you index into it if you need a contiguous buffer. You could provide a simple wrapper for this to maintain use of [x][y] indexing.

Comment: @John W.  Ok.  It seems to basically do the same thing as my answer, but I would still wrap it in a class, so as to keep that ugly code hidden as well as encapsulate the allocations and deallocation of the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I discovered the problem. Please see my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment `/* [nPhiCells][nThetaCells] */` in your class definition, I take it that you intent the `float**` to be 2D arrays. However, if you can use them like 2D arrays, they are actually arrays of *pointers* to arrays. That is a huge difference: it means, you have to copy `nPhiCells` individual arrays of `nThetaCells` elements *and* you have to setup the pointer array itself. Now, when you do

```
memcpy(mGridHalf[0], cur->mGridHalf[0],sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
```

in your copy constructor, you assume that there is no pointer array, and that all line arrays are sequential in memory. Either this copy exceeds the bounds of the pointer array (segfaulting), or accessing you array via `mGridHalf[i][j]` simply does the wrong thing, reinterpreting `float` data as pointers (and segfaulting).

---

Unfortunately, C++ is a horrible language for interacting with fortran multidimensional arrays because it has no notion of variable sized arrays. So the following is C code, not C++ code. In C, you can tackle the issue like this:

```
float (*mGridHalf)[nThetaCells] = malloc(nPhiCells*sizeof(*mGridHalf));
```

will correctly allocate and type a 2D array (i. e. an array of *arrays*) that can be accessed with

```
mGridHalf[phi][theta] = 7.3;
```

Since all elements are consecutive in memory, the entire thing can correctly be copied with

```
memcpy(mGridHalf, cur->mGridHalf, nPhiCells*sizeof(*mGridHalf));
```

and freed with

```
free(mGridHalf);
```

Technically, `mGridHalf` is now a pointer to an array, the pointer arithmetic that is invoked by the array access effectively does the same computation as if you had written:

```
float* foo = malloc(nPhiCells*nThetaCells*sizeof(*foo));
foo[phi*nThetaCells + theta] = 7.3;
```

However, using the correct pointer type `float (*)[nThetaCells]` allows you to avoid doing the index computation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @cmaster. Unfortunately, I do need to do this in c++.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely you're assuming that float** has data that is one contiguous chunk of memory.  If so, here is one way of accomplishing this.  First, I show the wrong way (but used often):

```
float** createFloat2D(int nRows, int nCols)
{
    float** p1 = new float*[nRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < nCols; ++i )
       p1[i] =  new float[nCols];
    return p1;
}

void destroyFloat2D(float**f, int nRows, int nCols)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < nCols; ++i )
       delete [] f[i];
   delete [] f;
}
```

Looks simple, and works for most purposes, but will fail if the assumption is made that the data is in a contiguous chunk of memory.

The other way to create a 2D array is to make the data contiguous.

```
float** createFloat2D(int nRows, int nCols)
{
    float** p1 = new float*[nRows];  // allocate row pointers
    float* p2 = new float[nRows * nCols];  // allocate data in one chunk
    for (int i = 0; i < nCols; ++i, p2 += nCols )
       p1[i] = p2;  // point the row pointers into the pool of memory
    return p1;
}

void destroyFloat2D(float**f)
{
   delete [] f[0];
   delete [] f;
}
```

Note above that the data is created in one contiguous "pool".  Now, using `yourArray[0]` actually points to the beginning of this memory.  Also note that destruction is done without having to know the number of rows or columns, since f[0] points to the pool of memory.

So now, code like this should work

```
float** mGridB = createFloat2D(nThetaCells, nPhiCells);
//...
memcpy(mGridB[0], cur->mGridB[0], sizeof(float)*nThetaCells*nPhiCells);
```

The code above now works correctly, if we use the second method of creating the 2d array.

I would still stick with the vector for 1-d float arrays, as you have the pointer to the data (see my earlier comment).  For the code above, I would wrap it in a class that handles creation and destruction easily.

The last thing is the copy constructor.  A copy constructor in C++ has the following possible signatures:

```
DGCPM(const DGCPM&);
DGCPM(DGCPM&);
DGCPM(volatile DBCPM&);
```

I may have missed one, but the signature should be one of those above, more than likely, the first one (you can also have additional arguments after the reference argument, but they all must have default values).

Note that a `DBCPM*` is not a valid argument for a copy constructor as your code stated -- remember that a copy constructor is not only for use, but also the compiler will use it to make copies.  So to signal the compiler that "yes, this function is used to make copies", your function must match one of the signatures above.

In addition, you need an assignment operator, in other words, the class needs to implement the "rule of 3".

Comment: I'm going to try this. On the main function side, I would swap out the deletes (which were probably wrong) for an object function function using your destroyFloat2D method on each 2D array, right?

Comment: If I get what you're saying - yes.  So instead of this:

`float** mGridB;`

It would be: `Your2DArray mGridB;`  and then Your2DArray is a class that handles the 2d array.

Comment: I'm running into that exact problem that DGCPM* is not a valid argument. How would I change that?

Comment: A valid argument to which function?

Comment: What is the proper syntax to use on the main function side? m[i] = new class DGCPM(cur[currentidx]); doesn't work since DGCPM* is not a valid argument to a constructor.

Comment: @John W. It is hard to see what you're trying to do.  Are you creating a 2d array of DGCPM?

Comment: Basically, yes. Each DGCPM is a model. So "m" and "cur" point to the array of models (referenced by m[0], m[1],...m[4], etc.)

Comment: Don't think this needs to be contiguous though, right? You can just replace "`float**`" with `DGCPM**` in my answer. But then it would be more worth it if you created a C++ class templated on the type instead of having to maintain two pieces of code that do practically the same thing.